# MVC Update View based on a drop down list in a for each loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is populated by a foreach loop. Each row in the table has a dropdown list and I want to use the value of that dropdown list to calculate another value on the same row in the view.

I am new to Jquery and have tried everything but it only works on the first row in the table.

Any advice would be appreciated.

View Code

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<VmShoppingCartCatalogue>
@using Mojito.Domain.ViewModels
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            updatePrice();
        });


        function updatePrice() {
            $('#TypeOfSubscription').each(function (e) {
                $('#TypeOfSubscription').change(function () {
                    var subscriptionType = $('#TypeOfSubscription').val();
                    var name = $('#Name').val();
                    var price = $('#Price').val();
                    var totalUsers = $('#NoOfUsers').val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("GetSubscriptionPrice", "ShoppingCartCatalogue", new {Area = "ECommerce"})",
                        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data: { 'subscriptionType': subscriptionType, 'name': name, 'price': price, 'totalUsers': totalUsers }

                    })
                    .success(function (result) {
                        $('#Price').val(result);
                        $('#price').text(result);

                    })
                    .error(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        if (xhr.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internal error: ' + xhr.responseText);
                        } else {
                            alert('Unexpected error.');
                        };
                    });
                });
            });
        }


    </script>
}




@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Mojito Products</h2>
<div class="col-md-9"></div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ShoppingCartCatalogue", "ShoppingCartCatalogue", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }
</div>

<div class="container col-md-12">


    <table class="table col-md-12">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().ImageData)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Category", "ShoppingCartCatalogue", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SortByCategory, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Product", "ShoppingCartCatalogue", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SortByProduct, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().TypeOfSubscription)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.ActionLink("Price per user", "ShoppingCartCatalogue", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SortByPrice, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().NoOfUsers)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().TotalPrice)
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>

        </tr>

        @foreach (VmShoppingCartCatalogue t in Model)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @if (t.ImageData != null)
                        {
                            <div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px">
                                <img class="img-thumbnail" width="60" height="75"
                                     src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ShoppingCartCatalogue",
                                          new { t.MojitoProductId })" />
                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.Category, new { Name = "Category", id = "Category" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.Name, new { Name = "Name", id = "Name" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.Description, new { Name = "Description", id = "Description" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(modelItem => t.TypeOfSubscription, new { Name = "TypeOfSubscription", id = "TypeOfSubscription", align = "left" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div id="price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.Price, new { Name = "Price", id = "Price" })</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => t.NoOfUsers, new { Name = "NoOfUsers", id = "NoOfUsers", type = "number", min = "1", width = "10" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => t.TotalPrice, new { Name = "TotalPrice", id = "TotalPrice" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (Request.Url != null)
                        {
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.TypeOfSubscription, new { Name = "TypeOfSubscription", id = "TypeOfSubscription" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.NoOfUsers, new { Name = "NoOfUsers", id = "NoOfUsers" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.MojitoProductId, new { Name = "MojitoProductId", id = "MojitoProductId" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.Category, new { Name = "Category", id = "Category" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.Name, new { Name = "Name", id = "Name" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.Description, new { Name = "Description", id = "Description" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.Price, new { Name = "Price", id = "Price" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.TotalPrice, new { Name = "TotalPrice", id = "TotalPrice" })
                            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>



            }

        }
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
</div>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("ShoppingCartCatalogue",
        new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are rendering duplicate IDs for the element in each row, so `var subscriptionType = $('#TypeOfSubscription').val();` will get the value of the first element with `id="TypeOfSubscription"` (the one in the first row).

Add a classname for `TypeOfSubscription`, then get the associated elements in the row using relative selectors. For example

```
$('.TypeOfSubscription').change(function () {
    var columns = $(this).closest('tr').children('td');
    var subscriptionType = $(this).val();
    var price = columns.eq(8).find('input').eq(6).val(); // assume you want the hidden input value but again you have 2 duplicate ID's within the same row!
    var totalUsers = columns.eq(6).find('input').val();
```

Note: there is no need to set the id and name attributes using `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => t.TypeOfSubscription, new { Name = "TypeOfSubscription", id = "TypeOfSubscription" })`. Both attributes are based on the property name (TypeOfSubscription) so they will both be "TypeOfSubscription" any way, and html helpers ignore any attempt to manually set the name attribute.

Note 2: apart from the invalid html because of the duplicate ID's, `<form>` elements cannot be child elements of `<table>`

Comment: Thanks.  My problem at present is I cannot get the event to even fire on the subsequent rows.  I am not sure I understand why these lines of code do not at least fire an event for each dropdown box.    $('#TypeOfSubscription').each(function (e) {
                $('#TypeOfSubscription').change(function () {          .  In regards to your note on the Html.Hiddenfor.  I am not sure why I need to do this, however if I take them out the values do not pass to the controller.  I would have assumed that because all my data rows are inside the form that they would pass across but this is not the case

Comment: Because all you elements have the same ID. And you do not need the enclosing `$('#TypeOfSubscription').each(function (e) {..` loop or the `function updatePrice() {`. Just put the `$('.TypeOfSubscription').change(function () {...})` in the document ready function

Comment: Great - thank you.  I now have the event firing on each drop down box.  Now I will take a look at logic for pulling the right values.    So essentially as I understand the change event will work on multiple cases of a .class but will not work on multiple cases of a #id reference

Comment: Duplicate ID's are not only invalid html but they make it almost impossible to work with jquery selectors particularly as `$('#someID').val()` will always return the value of the first element with `id="someID" and ignore all the rest. So you should always use classnames in these circumstances.

Comment: You might also want to consider using AJAX to post this data (i.e. add to the shopping cart) so the user can stay on the page and continue adding further items. I'm also confused why you have so many hidden inputs - surely they are not all needed just to add an item to the cart (e.g. `Description`) - typically the productID and quantity should be sufficient. You appear to be rendering a lot of unnecessary controls and posting them back which will degrade performance - a sure fire way to have users stay away from your site.

Comment: Ajax to post data is next on my list.  thanks for the advice.  I have it all working now.